# How to prepend a child item in qtreewidgetitem?

Tags: qt, qtreewidgetitem

I want to keep the latest child nodes always to in the top level items in qtreewidget, how is this possible ?

Normally `QTreeWidgetItem::addChild()` append the child item,  so I tried  `QTreeWidgetItem::insertChild(0, childItem)` but this doesnt helped me.

I am using  Qt 4.8.4 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit), in Win 7.

Comment: Can you specify Qt version? What status of sorting? Enabled or disabled?

Comment: I included qt version in my post, I have not done anything for sorting, I hope sorting is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in documentation of [QTreeWidgetItem::insertChild](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#insertChild) that if a child item is already inserted in your tree widget, insert it again will not produce any effect.

Then a workaround would be to use [QTreeWidget::removeChild](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#removeChild) before, and after that insert it at the first place.

Comment: Yes, I have tried insertChild, but it does not helped me, now I corrected my post.